# JSSIP application is not hearable in some nets?

Tags: javascript, sip, freeswitch, jssip

Why this can be so, that JSSIP application (connected to Freeswitch) is absolutely silent on some networks and works normal on other?

As I could found, namely network matters.

Server is always the same, computers are different, browsers are different. But they work in one network but does not work in others.

No any error messages in Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

The corporate firewall is likely to filter the voice traffic.

Comment: How to catch it? What ports to check?